# jquery ajax post request Access-Control-Request-Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an `AJAX` request to my server. The first time i did this with reference to lib (in web) in a `<script>` tag in my html document. I did it this using the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: api_url + "movie/create",
  type : "POST",
  contentType : 'application/json',
  data : JSON.stringify(form_data),
  success : function(response) {
    do something
  },
  error: function(xhr, resp, text){
      show error
  }
});
```

I got this request:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ru,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:*****
Referer:****
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 YaBrowser/17.10.0.2017 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Than i started to refactor my app, and download lib from npm ("npm i jquery"). So if i do request the same way (as shown above), i get this request:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:ru,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:***
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 YaBrowser/17.10.0.2017 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
```

And the server responds with the error `Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`.

So, how can i post request with `content-type` header instead of `Access-Control-Request-Headers`?

Comment: That means you are going a cross domain call....

Comment: try removing the content-type entirely, add a property called processData and set it to false. Basically what is happening is the resource you are posting to has a list of allowed headers, and content-type is not in that list so it is going to deny any requests that send that header. do you own the resource you are posting too?

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak the point is that i do post request twice with different versions of lib. Requests are sent to the same resource. I need to understand why i have different requests and how can i do this request equal

Answer (score 0):

You problem is in the server side. The browser for security only accept request from the same domain. So you need allow all origins request in you backend or you could create an array with specific origins.

Comment: okay. when i transfer my site to host, it started to work. But, the question is why the same function of the same lib create two different requests?

Comment: Two differents requests? Are you meaning a HEAD and POST request?

Comment: i mean, that i got two requests with different headers

Comment: So the first time, did you use a CDN? what version of jquery? 3.2?

Comment: What is CDN? jQuery is 3.2 both times

Comment: I mean if you import jquery using this: <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: You've a cross origin resource origin problem. If you want an alternative way to make the request use JSONP method. If you using nodejs read this article that can help you: https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Answer (score 0):

try put this on your ajax call under the "`url: api_url + "movie/create",`"

```
  dataType: "JSONP",
```

Comment: same thing. request was rejected by server